# Android, ListView, ArrayAdapter and formatting text

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to accomblish the following task:

- A ListView, with textview rows
- When I click on an item, the text changes to italic

The change to italic can be something else - the point is to change the text in some way.

I thought to use Html.fromHtml, since that's pretty easy to deal with when formatting text. However, I cannot get it to work accross my design.

In my main activity, I create and access the ListView and ArrayAdapter like this:

```
lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.itemslist);
```

I have a method for creating/updating the adapter, so that I can update the contents of the list:

```
private void displayList () {
   adapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_listitem, items);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

}
```

My OnItemClickListener:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(ShoppingListApp02Activity.this, "List item selected:" + 
        items.get(position).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    items.get(position).setName("<i>" + items.get(position).getName() + "</i>");
    displayList();
});
```

As you can see, on select/click of an item, I send the item's name surrounded by the html tags, to the Item class' setName() method. The name (type String) of the item object is now "<i>name</i>"

The setName() method in the Item class:

```
public void setName (String nname) { this.name = nname; }
```

Now, in the ArrayAdapter class (ItemArrayAdaper.java), the name is set in the TextView row of the ListView:

```
itemName.setText(item.name);
```

If I leave the code above as it is, when clicking the item in the list, the name changes to this: "<i>name</i>.

So far, it's as I expected.

However, from there I need to convert the string "<i>name</i> to the html result, namely "*name*". But when I try that like this:

```
itemName.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.name).toString());
```

it simply skips the html tags and displays the name string normally.

Why isn't the fromHtml working here?

To compare, I tried just setting the contents of another TextView in my application (the footer) in the same way, with just:

```
footerview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i><font color='#123456'>text</font></i>"));
```

And that worked just fine. But somewhere along the path, the tags surrounding the item name is lost. And that's strange, because in the ItemArrayAdapter class when I don't try to convert from html, the tags are there. They just aren't honored when using the fromHtml method at the same place.

Any ideas?

And, I know there's probably a better way to do this, and I'd be interested in that too :-)

Comment: Did you try to remove the `toString()` here
`itemName.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.name).toString());`

Comment: Well, maybe you could add some `Log.i("debug","item.name="+item.name)` before your `itemName.setText(...)` line, and show us the result...

Comment: do you need to use the html tags <i> to make it italic? you can just make it like this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textStyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution: Remove the toString(). I didn't try that because I had problems with it before, thinking that the data passed to a TextView HAS to be a pure string. However, it works like a charm without the toString() :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about a different approach?

As you stated

> I'm trying to accomblish the following task:
>
> - A ListView, with textview rows.
> - When I click on an item, the text changes to italic

Simply, initialize :

```
lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.itemslist);
private void displayList () {
   adapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_listitem, items);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

}
```

And in your onItemClickListener()

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(ShoppingListApp02Activity.this, "List item selected:" + 
        items.get(position).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ((TextView)view).setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);


});
```

Simple enough?

Comment: I like that solution, but I'm not sure how it would work in this example. I'm setting the string in the Item object, and then the ArrayAdapter class puts it in the TextView. So, since I'm storing the string before putting it in the TextVeiw, it seems easier to let the formatting be embedded in the string. Or am I missing an easier way of doing it?

Comment: Yup, I get it. Much more elegant, I'd say. However, your example crashes with a ClassCastException.

Comment: i'm assuming `R.layout.item_listitem` is a TextView. If it is, you do the error handling, i can only share the idea :-)

Comment: Realise I'm a bit late to the party, but I just tried this and it worked like a charm.  Just need to work out how to change that italic to strike-through, and all is good.  Thanks,